# Using Front Derailleur Over the Stated Max Capacity

Tags: derailleur-front

Im planning to run a 54-36t/34t chainring setup and looking for compatible derailleurs. Looking at  [shimano claris FD-R2000](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/claris-r2000/FD-R2000-F.html). It's stated that the total capacity is 16t. Im wondering if it would still work with what my planned setup which has a difference of 18t (or even 20t).

Im aware some of the rated capacities shimano has written are soft limits (I have used rear derailleurs above their max teeth limit with little issues). I wonder if it also applied to the front.

Also, since 3x FDs usually have higher capacities, Im also wondering if a [tourney tz FD-TZ500](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney-tz500/FD-TZ500-DS6.html) will also work on a 54-36t/34t.

Comment: You almost have two distinct questions here: Does a 2x FD have this capacity/capability and will that work?   And, Does a 3x FD work if a 2x FD does not work (or work well)?  Input from others requested.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, doing this at all is likely to result in bad shifting for a lot of reasons, even if it works. The chainring shift assist features and intended chain contact spots on the front derailleur won't be located correctly, and that will be true at the same time that the chain is being asked to go a bigger distance than FDs have ever typically been able to handle moving them all at once. It will be at its worst with an indexed shifter, and with friction you may gain a little from being able to finesse the shift.

When you exceed a double FD capacity like this, the first consequence will be that at some point while on the small ring and shifting in back in the smaller cog direction, the chain will start dragging on the tail end of the cage where it passes over. You can't just ignore this; if you use that gear, you'll grind through the cage. Without testing, predicting which is the first combination to do this is impractical, but from what I've seen the published limit on Shimano FDs is "hard" enough to say that there will very likely be a point where it happens. Since these gear combinations are getting into the realm of cross-gears, how much it matters that they won't be usable is up to you.

Doing it with a triple FD will tend to result in the problem that when the FD height is set correctly to clear the big ring with minimal gap, the chain contact area of the inner cage won't be where you want it to be when you it to be there to shift from small to large. In other words, because you're only using about half of the FD's intended lateral movement, there's not enough vertical movement happening fast enough. I've seen this kind of experiment go wrong for this reason but don't know what exceptions might be out there to get around it.

Using a mountain/hybrid type triple FD like the Tourney linked to with an intended large chainring of 42 will never work well with a road-size ring like a 50t+. It also won't index correctly with any Shimano road left shifter.

Comment: Then what FD would you recommend for the 54-36t / 54-34t setup Im planning to use?

Comment: @BanjoPanesa Not enough information, i.e. we don't know what shifter type you're using (drop vs flat bar) and what speed generation you're limited to if any - you mention Tourney and Claris, but does that mean this must be an 8-speed bike? At the end of the day, if this is something you're going to do, the options are basically hack (grind, refabricate, etc) the cage or accept not being able to use certain gears.

Comment: If you really and truly want 54t and a double on a bike with very wide range, a better way to do it is use a stock 54/40 crank, an FD made to work with a ring that large (various mostly upper-end 10- and 11-speed Shimano road FDs), and get the range by running a wider cassette and any of the various tricks to enable it, depending on the numbers chosen and what shifter type you need. That way you at least have something that shifts good. The conversation at that point becomes pretty well trodden mullet drivetrain stuff.

Comment: yes it's an 8 speed dropbar mini velo. The wide range is to compensate for the small wheels.

Comment: @BanjoPanesa Presuming you've got the compatible R2000 Claris STI (and not a previous 8-speed generation that won't be "long arm" FD compatible), then I think it probably makes the most sense to do the FD-R2000, keep it within capacity, do 54-38, and 11-34 in back. The low gear there is still extremely low on 20" and you don't have to do anything particularly weird to get it. There are many compatible RDs that could complete that setup. You'd be going over the max tooth spec of the FD by 2t, which is a small experiment but probably fine.

Comment: And unless you really needed that low gear, 54/40 would be better yet, because then you can actually get a chainring set made to work together and the shift will be better.

Comment: Yes, I do have the a claris r2000. Haven't mentioned it but my current setup is a 54-42t paired with a 11-40t.  I still find the lowest gear there lacking for the steep roads so that's why I was planning to go even lower. My RD is pretty much at it's actual limit so getting a smaller chainring at the front is probably the best option. 

`going over the max tooth spec of the FD by 2t, which is a small experiment but probably fine.`   
thanks for the replies. this was the answer I was looking for. will probably look for someone who actually tried it though first.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used a 9100-series Dura Ace front derailleur with a 20-tooth spread (48-28) between chainrings. Shifting takes a little more care, but it does work.

I would assume that 11-speed Ultegra and 105 parts would work as well.